# Extract data based on 2 tables where record not matched on 1 or multiple fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I am now trying extracting data from 2 different tables that doe's not matching the same record in 1 or multiple fields

```
TABLE 1
----------------------------------
ID          NAME            MEMBER          SMS_MEMBER
1           JOHN            YES             NO
2           JOY             'NO'            NO
3           SMITH           NO              'YES'
4           ANDRES          YES             YES
5           JIMMY           NO              YES


TABLE 2
----------------------------------
ID          NAME            MEMBER          SMS_MEMBER
1           JOHN            YES             NO
2           JOY             'YES'           NO
3           SMITH           NO             'NO'
4           ANDRES          YES             YES
5           JIMMY           NO              YES
```

Here is my logical query

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
WHERE 
TABLE1.ID NOT IN TABLE2.ID 
OR
TABLE1.NAME NOT IN TABLE2.NAME 
OR
TABLE1.EMAIL_MEMBER NOT IN TABLE2.EMAIL_MEMBER
OR
TABLE1.SMS_MEMBER NOT IN TABLE2.SMS_MEMBER;
```

The extracted record will be

```
----------------------------------
ID          NAME            MEMBER          SMS_MEMBER
2           JOY             'NO'            NO
3           SMITH           NO              'YES'
```

Since below record is matched it will be excluded from the final extract after the query

### EXCLUDED RECORD

```
ID          NAME            MEMBER          SMS_MEMBER
1           JOHN            YES             NO
4           ANDRES          YES             YES
5           JIMMY           NO              YES
```

Would be great if you guys help me on this too, please.

Comment: `TABLE1.ID NOT IN TABLE2.ID ` will exclude all rows.

Comment: @Cid there is an OR which excludes all the names and another OR which excludes all the members and another OR which excludes all the sms_members.

Comment: Ah yeah there is no join, that's not entries by entries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple method uses aggregation.  Assuming no duplicates in either table:

```
select id, name, member, sms_member
from ((select id, name, member, sms_member
       from table1
      ) union all
      (select id, name, member, sms_member
       from table2
      )
     ) t
group by id, name, member, sms_member
having count(*) = 1;
```

However, your sample data suggests that you just want rows in `table2` that are not in `table1`.  If so, I recommend `not exists`:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where not exists (select 1
                  from table1 t1
                  where t1.id = t2.id and t1.name = t2.name and t1.member = t2.member an t1.sms_member = t2.sms_member
                 );
```

The logic needs to be tweaked if `NULL` values are possible in any columns.

Comment: there are no NULL values, all values have either true or false but i have 2 tables so i want to match where values has been changed

Answer (score 0):

You need a `left join`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1 left join table2 t2
on t2.id = t1.id and t2.name = t1.name and t2.email_member = t1.email_member and t2.sms_member = t1.sms_member
where t2.id is null
```

The matching records will be excluded because for them `t2.id` is not `null`.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qK51ynH4qRPnpfJHvxfeLu/0).
Results:

```
| id  | name  | email_member | sms_member |
| --- | ----- | ------------ | ---------- |
| 2   | JOY   | NO           | NO         |
| 3   | SMITH | NO           | YES        |
```